# Please tell me how to use Matrix.row_insert in sympy

Tags: python

I have the following error.
AttributeError: the object 'list' has no attribute 'bags'
Tell me how to produce as follows.
Matrix ([[-4, 1, 9], [1, 2, -4], [2, -3, 6]])

```
from sympy import *
var('myMatrix')
mylist=[[0]*3]*3e
mylist[0]=[-4, 1, 9]
mylist[1]=[1, 2, -4]
mylist[2]=[2, -3, 6]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i-1, mylist[i])
print("# ",myMatrix)
```

Answer (score 0):

I get an error when I try to insert a list with row_insert.
Rewriting two places as below should work.

```
from sympy import *
var('myMatrix')
mylist=[[0]*3]*3  # FIX
mylist[0]=[-4, 1, 9]
mylist[1]=[1, 2, -4]
mylist[2]=[2, -3, 6]
myMatrix=Matrix()
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    print(mylist[i])
    myMatrix = myMatrix.row_insert(i, Matrix([mylist[i]])) # FIX

print("# ",myMatrix)
```